# RDD lookup inside a transformation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have 2 paired RDDs like below

RDD1 contains name as key and zipcode as value:

> RDD1 -> RDD( (ashley, 20171), (yash, 33613), (evan, 40217) )

RDD2 contains zip code as key and some random number as value:

> RDD2 -> RDD( (20171, 235523), (33613, 345345345), (40189, 44355217),
>   (40122, 2345235), (40127, 232323424) )

I need to replace the zipcodes in RDD1 with the corresponding values from RDD2. So the output would be

> RDD3 -> RDD( (ashley, 235523), (yash, 345345345), (evan, 232323424) )

I tried doing it using the RDD lookup method like below but I got exception saying that RDD transformations cannot be perfomed inside another RDD transformation

```
val rdd3 = rdd1.map( x => (x._1, rdd2.lookup(x._2)(0)) )
```

Comment: You can't do that. If `rdd2` is small, you could collect it on the driver and broadcast it, then what you're trying would be possible. Otherwise, you'll probably have to play with joins to achieve what you want.

Comment: Do you mean something like this?   val zipmap = Map("40217" -> "Alabama", "40222" -> "Alaska", "20127" -> "miami", "33613" -> "herndon", "40111" -> "tampa")
   val broadcastVar = sc.broadcast(zipmap)
   val user_zip_lookup = user_zip_pair.map( x => (x._1, broadcastVar.value(x._2)) )

Comment: Yes, that's the gist of it if you can broadcast the data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yon can simply join 2 RDDs by zipcode:

```
rdd1.map({case (name, zipcode) => (zipcode, name)})
    .join(rdd2)
    .map({case (zipcode, (name, number)) => (name, number)})
    .collect()
```

Note, this will return only records, that have matching zipcodes in rdd1 and rdd2. If you want to set some default number to records in rdd1, that doesn't have corresponding zipcode in rdd2, use *leftOuterJoin* insted of *join*:

```
rdd1.map({case (name, zipcode) => (zipcode, name)})
    .leftOuterJoin(rdd2)
    .map({case (zipcode, (name, number)) => (name, number.getOrElse(0))})
    .collect()
```

Comment: @Vvitaliy Thanks for the answer. Letz say that there is key called other in rdd2. How do we set the value of other to the records in rdd1 that doesn't have a match?

Comment: Here you are just assuming that the value of other is 0. What if we don't know the value of other and pick it from the rdd2?

Comment: with `leftOuterJoin` it picks value `number` from rdd2, if exists record in rdd2 which satisfies condition `rdd1.zipcode == rdd2.zipcode`, if not, it set the value to 0. if can set it to any value you want, but if your want to pick it by some logic from rdd2, you need to perform more sophisticated join, depending on that logic.